# osql not able to find Driver in odb.ini file

Tags: sql, linux, ubuntu, odbc, freetds

my freetds.conf file:

```
    [global]
        # TDS protocol version
;   tds version = 7.4

# A typical Sybase server
[egServer50]
    host = symachine.domain.com
    port = 5000
    tds version = 5.0

# A typical Microsoft server
[ABC]
    host = IP address
    port = 1433
    tds version = 7.4
```

my odbc.ini file

```
     [ABC]

    Driver = FreeTDS
    Description = ODBC connection via FreeTDS
    Trace = No
    Server = IP address
    port = 1433
    Database = DA_DB
    TDS_Version = 7.4

[default]

Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
```

my odbcinst.ini file:

```
 [FreeTDS]
Description = TDS driver (MS SQL)
# Some installations may differ in the paths
#Driver = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
#Setup = /usr/lib/odbc/libtdsS.so
Driver = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so
Setup = /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so
CPTimeout =
CPReuse =
FileUsage = 1
```

The output for osql is

```
 osql -S ABC -U sa -P 123
checking shared odbc libraries linked to isql for default directories...
strings: '': No such file
    trying /tuH ... no
    trying /tmp/sql ... no
    trying /tmp/sql ... no
    trying /etc ... OK
checking odbc.ini files
    reading /home/hadoopuser/.odbc.ini
[ABC] found in /home/hadoopuser/.odbc.ini
found this section:
looking for driver for DSN [ABC] in /home/hadoopuser/.odbc.ini
  no driver mentioned for [ABC] in .odbc.ini
looking for driver for DSN [default] in /home/hadoopuser/.odbc.ini
osql: error: no driver found for [ABC] in .odbc.ini
```

Not able to understand the problem here. I am running these codes from ubuntu 16.04. Please any suggestions as what might be the problem...

Comment: Enter the driver for ABC as /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsodbc.so in you odbc.ini file.

Comment: Still same result.. Its not reading a single thing from my odbc.ini file..

Comment: One more thing my odbc.ini file is saved in /etc why is it showing in /home/hadoopuser... Can that be the issue?

Comment: Bacause hadoop/osql not doubt is configured to use this file

Comment: So what can be the solution for it???

Comment: Change your config files or alternatively copy the config files from /etc to /home